# Need to ask something about Designs in android?

Tags: android, button

In Apps like Google NewsStand, when we scroll the `MainUI`, the developer has used buttons with `ImageView`. He has created each button or there is some shortcut to it? Because creating each and every button takes a lot of time.

Comment: @codeMagic sorry m just a beginner in android!! can we  set the height of list views to the extent which is seen in the Newsstand app?

Comment: I don't know what the newstand app looks like but a `ListView` height should be `match_parent` and you can set the row heights to whatever you want

Comment: THankx @codeMagic :D !! If you dont mind can u write a sample code?

Comment: No because since their is no code for me to fix of yours, I would just be writing a tutorial which is not what this site is meant for. There are plenty of good ListView tutorials on the Google. Give it a try and when you get stuck post a question with relevant code and information. I believe in you

Comment: Thankx @codeMagic i will do it as u say!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an adapter and override the getView method to load images to the listview, use the "position" variable to load the appropriate image:

```
public class myAdap extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
    //load the content of image base on "position"
    return v;
}
```

}